# In PowerShell, how to save a DateTime variable into a file to be retrieved later?

Tags: powershell, date-time, timestamp, json

I want to log the timestamp when a certain line is executed so that the script can know how long it has passed since last execution of that line, even if the script is stopped in between and the timestamp saved as variable gets lost.

I tried saving the timestamp by

```
(Get-Date) | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "$($env:TEMP)\LastTimeChecked.json"
```

and reading the timestamp by

```
[DateTime]$LastTimeChecked=(Get-Content "$($env:TEMP)\LastTimeChecked.json" | ConvertFrom-Json)
```

But PowerShall cannot convert the data stored in Json back to DateTime format anymore. The file is saved as follows:

```
"value":  "\/Date(1656291839853)\/",
"DisplayHint":  2,
"DateTime":  "Monday, 27. June 2022 00:03:59"
```

How to retrieve the timestamp from this Json file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160853/convertfrom-json-not-converting-datetime

Answer (score 3):

If you need to parse that date string into a DateTime object on the same machine (or one that is installed with the same regional settings as the one you saved the file with), you can use:

```
$date = (Get-Content "$($env:TEMP)\LastTimeChecked.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).DateTime
$LastTimeChecked = [datetime]::ParseExact($date, 'dddd, dd. MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)  # or [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture instead of $null
```

If you are not sure what regional datetime settings the reader machine has, use

```
$date = (Get-Content "$($env:TEMP)\LastTimeChecked.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).DateTime
$LastTimeChecked = [datetime]::ParseExact($date, 'dddd, dd. MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I finally opted for converting all the DateTime format variables to Integer variables of Unix timestamp (Get-Date -UFormat %s -Milliseconds 0) to make things easier.